# Integrability Criterion of Riemann-Stieltjes integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, proof-verification, proof-explanation

I have the proof of Integrability Criterion for Riemann-stieltjes integrals, but there is some steps that I don't understand.

Theorem:

Suppose $f$ is a function that is bounded on $I=[a,b]$ and $\alpha$ is monotonically increasing in $I$. If $f$ is Riemann-Stieltjes integrable ($f\in R(\alpha)$), then for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a partition $P$ of $I$ such that $U(P,f,\alpha)-L(P,f,\alpha)<\epsilon$.

Proof:

Let $\epsilon>0$.

For $P'[a,b]$ the set of all partitions of $[a,b]$,
$$\tag{1}\int_{a}^b f(x)d\alpha(x)=\inf_{P\in P'} U(P,f,\alpha) \ \ \text{ and }\int_{a}^b f(x)d\alpha(x)=\sup_{P\in P'} L(P,f,\alpha) .$$

Then $\epsilon/2 >0$ implies that there exists $P_1 \in P'[a,b]$ such that $$\int_{a}^b f(x)d\alpha(x)< U(P_1,f,\alpha) <\int_{a}^b f(x)d\alpha(x)+\epsilon/2$$ and there exiss $P_2 \in P'[a,b]$ such that $$\int_{a}^b f(x)d\alpha(x) -\epsilon/2< L(P_2,f,\alpha) <\int_{a}^b f(x)d\alpha(x).$$

Therefore,
$$
U(P_1,f,\alpha) -\int_{a}^b f(x)d\alpha(x)<\epsilon/2 \ \ \text{ and } \ \ -L(P_2,f,\alpha) +\int_{a}^b f(x)d\alpha(x)<\epsilon/2 .$$

Let $P$ be the common refinement of $P_1$ and $P_2$.

Thus,
$$U(P,f,\alpha) -\int_{a}^b f(x)d\alpha(x)<\epsilon/2$$ and $$-L($P,f,\alpha) +\int_{a}^b f(x)d\alpha(x)<\epsilon/2.$$

Finally,
$$
U(P_1,f,\alpha) -L(P_2,f,\alpha)< \epsilon  /2 + \epsilon /2= \epsilon.$$

> Why does $P_1$ and $P_2$ exist?
>
> What it means when it says: 'Let $P$ be the common refinement of $P_1$ and $P_2$' I mean is it equivalent to say $P=P_1\cap P_2$ ?
>
> At the beginning of the proof, why do we state $(1)$?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existence of $P_1$ and $P_2$ is due to the definition of supremum and infimum (and these two always exist because of the completeness of the reals).

The refinement is not the intersection (there is no reason for the two partitions to share any interval). If I have the partition $\{[0,1],(1,2]\}$ and the partition $\{[0,3/4],(3/4,5/4],(5/4,2]\}$, a refinement would be 
$$
\{[0,3/4],[3/4,1],(1,5/4], (5/4,2]\}.
$$

Finally, $(1)$ is the definition of integrability.

Comment: I know (1) is the definition of integrability but I think we don't need it in the proof.

Comment: So why to mention it?

Comment: That's a nice example to understand partitions, but how can I express it with symbols (in the proof) ? Is there a way?

Comment: Of course you need the definition. What you are trying to prove is that the definition implies something else. How could you expect not to use it?

Comment:  hum, that's not the definition of f being riemann-stieltjes, I have another one in my notes

Comment: but maybe it's equivalent

Comment: I don't know what you have in your notes, obviously. But the usual definition of Riemman (Stieltjes) integrable is that the supremum of the lower sums agrees with the infimum of the upper sums; and that's exactly what $(1)$ says.

Comment: ok thanks Martin